# Could you explain this calculation of tiling and offset?

Tags: unity, coordinates, uv-mapping, materials

I don't understand why we add `+colNumber` when we calculate the `offset = Vector2 ((uIndex+colNumber) * size.x`, which gives us `x=3` for the index 13, which is the square located at the coordinates `x:1, y:0` on the image (one square to the right, and "v" starts from the bottom). If the UV of the big image is on [0,1] for U and for V, why do we reach 3 for uIndex? And why don't we only do :

```
u = uIndex * sizeUV.x = 1 * 0.25 = 0.25
v = vIndex * sizeUV.y = 0 * 0.25 = 0
```

Here is the code from http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Animating_Tiled_texture_-_Extended :

```
// Calculate index
var index : int = Time.time * fps;
// Repeat when exhausting all cells
index = index % totalCells;

// Size of every cell
var size = Vector2 (1.0 / colCount, 1.0 / rowCount);

// split into horizontal and vertical index
var uIndex = index % colCount;
var vIndex = index / colCount;

// build offset
// v coordinate is the bottom of the image in opengl so we need to invert.
offset = Vector2 ((uIndex+colNumber) * size.x, (1.0 - size.y) - (vIndex+rowNumber) * size.y);

renderer.material.SetTextureOffset ("_MainTex", offset);
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get index 13? It's modulated by TotalCells, which is 4 (so it has to be 0,1,2 or 3). And I think that "+colNumber" is there just in case you want to start from some other column than 0. It's just starting offset.

Comment: @zacharmarz you're right, let's take 11, 11%16 = 11, then 11 % 4 (colCount) = 3, then (3+4) * 0.25 = 1.75 ... So the fourth blue head is at offsetX = 1.75 ? I don't understand.

Comment: @zacharmarz thanks, with totalCells being 4, it works indeed, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I understand it (I'm not saying that it's also how author of that script meant it):

Column count is total number of **tiles in sheet**. (the same for row)

Column number is **number of a tile, where your animation begins** (in picture in your question, it should be always 0, but you could also have for example 2 rows and 8 columns - 2 colors in one row).

Total cells is total number of **tiles in animation**.

Lets say you have the picture as is in your question, but you only want to animate last two faces (quick blinking) - these two: 8-) and :-)

So you will call function as this: SetSpriteAnimation(4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 10);

ColCount = 4

RowCount = 4

RowNumber = 2 (zero based and it's calculated from the top, because in the code author is inverting them)

ColNumber = 2 (zero based, so this is 3th column)

TotalCells = 2 (our animation has only 2 tiles)

FPS = 10 (doesn't matter)

If you try to put these values in script, index can be only 0 or 1 after line index = index % totalCells and OffsetX can be 0.5 or 0.75.

Lets say you want to animate blue faces from 2nd row (1 based indexing).

What is important: Your ColNumber has to be number of first tile of animation. TotalCells is total count of tiles in animation.

=============================

And about your comment to the question:

let's take 11, 11%16 = 11, then 11 % 4 (colCount) = 3, then (3+4) * 0.25 = 1.75 ... So the fourth blue head is at offsetX = 1.75 ? I don't understand.

Total cells count can't be 16 (it should be 4, because you are animating just one row, not all 4 rows), when your ColNumber is 4 (it should be 3, because it's 0 based). If you take ColCount = 3, your animation starts in 4th row and has only 1 frame.

If you have any questions to my answer, don't hesitate to ask. It's little complicated :)

Comment: OK thanks, I saw it as the total cells being 16, this is maybe what I did not understand. Thank you for the answer